# ftp_ssl_connection via php

Tags: php, ftp

Why when I'm trying to do:

```
$conn_id=ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result=ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
echo ftp_pwd($conn_id);
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

I get the following errors:

```
Warning: ftp_login() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/...
Warning: ftp_pwd() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/....
Warning: ftp_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given /home/...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means that `ftp_ssl_connect` returned false instead of a connection resource.  So likely either your $ftp_server url is incorrect, the server is refusing your connection, or there's some other connection error happening.

Answer (score 0):

Because [ftp_ssl_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php) returns FALSE.

> Returns a SSL-FTP stream on success or FALSE on error.